# Necesito mostrar las respuestas de un campo de selección en un formulario para actualizar los datos. estoy trabajando con marco iónic 4 y angular 6

Tags: angular6, ionic4

Capturo las respuestas con matrices y las recorro con un for.

```
<script>

 for( var i=0; i < this.respuestaEncuesta.length; i++){
    this.Form.opc[i] = rtasPreguntas['message'][i].respuesta;
    this.Form.obs[i] = rtasPreguntas['message'][i].observacion;}

</script>
```

Lo muestro en el ionic así.

```
    <html>
<ion-item>

        <ion-label >Opciones de Respuesta</ion-label>
         <ion-select 
                   interface="alert" 
                   placeholder="Seleccionar"
                   cancelText="Cancelar"
                   name="opc[i]"
                   [(ngModel)]="Form.opc[i]"
                   > 
     <ion-select-option  *ngFor="let opc of loadOpc[i]" [value]="opc {{opc.TITULO}
     </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
     </ion-item>
 </html>
```

Teóricamente, puedo mostrar las respuestas del campo de selección en la consola, pero, en la vista, eso no funciona.

Se llama el metodo que permite cargar las respuestas a las preguntas de esa encuesta

```
  <script>
           const rtasPreguntas = await this.editS.loadRtaPreguntas(editarEncuesta);

            console.log(rtasPreguntas );

           if (rtasPreguntas['error']!= 0){
            console.log(rtasPreguntas['message']);

          } else{
            this.respuestaEncuesta = rtasPreguntas['message'];  
this.titulo = rtasPreguntas['message'][0].titulo;
    </script>
```

SE ASIGNA CADA RESPUESTA A CADA PREGUNTA

```
<script>
        for( var i=0; i < this.respuestaEncuesta.length; i++){
        this.Form.opc[i] = rtasPreguntas['message'][i].respuesta;

        this.Form.obs[i] = rtasPreguntas['message'][i].observacion;

        let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + rtasPreguntas['message'][i].evidencia;
        this.foto[i] = base64Image

        const contrato = await this.MosSer.loadContrato();

          if( contrato['error'] != 0 ){
           console.log( contrato['message'] );

          }else {
            this.loadContrato = contrato['message'];

          }

           this.Utilser.closePresentLoading();
        } 
        }

      }

</script>
```

La idea es que en cada select se pueda mostrar la respuesta con la que llenaron el formulario, posteriormente poder habilitar el select para así poder escoger otra respuesta.

Comment: Hola! te encuentras en SO español, por favor traduce tu pregunta! :)

Comment: Gracias por la corrección

Comment: Usa angular y TypeScript en lugar de hacer eso. Por favor agrega el controlador de la vista y te explico como hacerlo

Comment: Un título contiene la idea general, la descripción del mismo va en el cuerpo del mensaje. Saludos :D

Comment: ya se agrego mas código de la vista

Answer (score 0):

Trata de usar lo siguiente.

```
<ion-select-option  *ngFor="let opc of loadOpc" [value]="{{opc.TITULO}}">
```

No puedes agregar el indice de `i` a la sentencia de `ngFor` porque esa funcion ya internamente te lo recorre, a menos de que fuese un arreglo dentro de otro solo asi funcionaria incluso siendo arreglos bidimensionales deberia de funcionar.

Por cierto elimine el primer `opc1` que tenias en el value, realmente no entiendo porque agregaste eso ahi ya que le mandas el value al poner `{{opc.TITULO}}` pero si lo necesitas vuelvelo a agregar.

A pesar del codigo que agregaste aun no entiendo de donde viene `loadOpc` pero si agregas mas codigo o el lugar de donde viene esa variable me seria de ayuda para darte una respuesta mas clara.

Comment: El [ i ] lo agrego por que estoy cargando las preguntas desde una base y me genere cards diferentes para cada pregunta y estas tienen diferentes opciones de respuesta las cuales cargo en el [ loadOpc ]

Comment: Se puede obtener el indice del arreglo (`i`) de esta manera: `*ngFor="let opc of loadOpc; let i = index"